# How to add Highcharts view data table option to the exports dropdown?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've a Highchart graph and I just want to be able to export the graph as a `csv`, `pdf` and show the table. I am not sure how to add the `show data table` option to this dropdown.

Here is the `exporting` configuration that I'm using:

```
{
  exporting: {
    buttons: {
      contextButton: {
        menuItems: ['downloadPDF', 'downloadCSV']
      }
    }
  },
  // ....more code here
}
```

I have pdf and the csv option but have no way to add the table option. Here is the link to the doc which lists the [export button options](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems).

Can anyone guide me how to just add the `show data table` option like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/export-data/categorized/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `'viewData'` to `menuItems`:

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        contextButton: {
            menuItems: ['downloadPDF', 'downloadCSV', 'viewData']
        }
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/na3v216L/

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've this script in place. If I remove the custom `exporting` section I get back the `show data table` option. But in my case I just want to show 3 of them viz pdf, csv and table.